# I don't get this simple trick - UI and list view

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have found the tutorial (author is inactive it seems) from link ->
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

My question is why there is additional **list_item.xml**, this even don't exist (at least is not visible to user) in main UI file

Main UI file have EditText and ListView, additional file (a custom control?) have a TextView which as I suppose is not a field where user is really typing, **but** it seems that in some way the application reads from it.

Where is the bridge between EditText in main UI file, and TextView from custom control?
Filtering data in ListView is based on **EditView**, but how the hell the content is passed to it if user is typing to **EditText** from another file

Sorry if this is a noob question, I guess it's related to adapter in the code, but usually I am writing desktop programs in C# and I can't imagine how this code works...

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
```

**R.id.product_name** is empty (in my thoughts)

The only thing that connects both fields are that they are in the same place on UI, but it is not possible to type in 2 fields at the same time... is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-#1 list_item.xml is referenced when setting up the adapter. It tells the adapter, hey for each item, inflate a layout that looks like this.  So if my listView's adapter getCount() returns 5, it will produce 5 items (rows) that look like list_item layout.

-#2 The textView is used to display the different phone names in the list view.  It's a label.  It's not a place for the user to type data.  That's the EditText.

-#3 The arrayAdapter constructor used here is a convenience type, in other words it makes assumptions about your data so that you the programmer don't have to do a lot of typing / configuring.  It assumes you have a layout (R.layout.list_item), that the layout contains a textView (R.id.product_name), and that you have some sort of collection/array of strings (products).  It knows the collection has Strings because we typed the ArrayAdapter by appending < String> to it.

It automatically assumes that the first String element of that collection or array is suppose to go in the textView of the first list_item it creates, and so forth.  If you hover your mouse over the constructor in eclipse it will tell you how the parameters are used.  There's plenty of lower level ways to program this stuff, but this method is often used in tutorials because it's easy to get up and running quickly.

Answer (score 2):

**list_item** is use to inflate rows in listview.

**What is inflation??**
Suppose you are pushing some air in a ballon and in the process you are actually inflating some air in the ballon.

Likewise when a listview is created,a view must be defined so that each and every row of the listview represent that view.And that view must be inflate within the listview.Each an every listview must inflate a view.And that view is recycled each and every time a new row is created in listview.

In this case that view is the `list_item.xml` file which contains a textview only.
**THAT TEXTVIEW IS INFLATED TO EACH AND EVERY ROW IN THE LIST.**

I think before advancing you must learn basic components of listview.See [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

`list_item.xml` is the template that repeated through your list items, and the `EditText` that filter data not related to it
when you type inside `EditText` the method `onTextChanged` execute and filter data with this `MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);` 
the method `filter` can override inside your adapter